# python convert part of a row of data frame to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Can someone explain to me why this expression works:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[['AccX', 'AccY']],axis=1).values
```

But these three give me the following error:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.array([x.AccX,x.AccY]),axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x[['AccX', 'AccY']]),axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: x[['AccX', 'AccY']].values,axis=1)
```

Error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14258, 2), indices imply (14258, 11)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When asking questions, you should provide a minimal viable working example so that others can recreate and troubleshoot your stated problem.  For example, the first five rows of your dataframe with the two relevant columns in this case.  `x[['AccX', 'AccY']].to_dict('list')` [ask]

Comment: you don't even need to use `apply`: `df[['AccX', 'AccY']].values`

Comment: But if I want to do some operation on each row, I still need `apply` correct? Also I kind of just want to know why the first three don't work. My whole data frame has 11 columns